# SOLARIS 10 Date Arithmetic

Tags: date, solaris

I am using X86 SOLARIS 10 and need the following bash script to get yesterday's date.

```
   #!/usr/local/bin/bash
   #ds=`date '+%Y%m%d' -d "+2 days"`
       ds=`GMT+24 date +%Y%m%d`
   #ds=`date --date yesterday +%Y%m%d`
   echo $ds
```

Getting an error "GMT+24: command not found". Also, tried the methods that are commented without success. Any suggestion

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say `TZ=GMT+24 date +%Y%m%d`... But I've no idea whether the C library will consider that a valid time zone... "`GMT+24`" is indeed generally not a valid command, so the shell is correct in whining about that.

Comment: I'm not sure the Solaris `date` command can do what you're trying to do. If you can install the GNU Coreutils package, `date -d tomorrow` will work. If not, consider writing a program in another language (either C or Perl would work well).

Comment: @KeithThompson is right - Solaris does not by default come with the GNU coreutils date command - which is what you are trying to use.  You need to find and  go to plan B.  The /usr/sfw/bin directory is the home of the few coreutils you do have.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do much date arithmetic with Solaris's own `date` command. As others have pointed out you'll need **GNU date**.

See this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/solaris-default-install-user-tools), which includes information on getting GNU date (part of GNU coreutils package) on Solaris. Make it a rule to always deploy the minimal GNU tools on your Solaris servers (see link). Make it part of your company's default install. Then you won't get into these issues. Or move to more recent Solaris(*) where GNU date is installed by default.

*) Solaris 10 is getting fairly old now that we're in Dec 2014.