# How to subtract or add days or months to a date on Solaris?

Tags: date, unix, command-line, solaris

Linux `date` has the `-d` feature which is missing in Solaris. So how can I go about subtracting or adding days or months to a date on Solaris.

Comment: I do have */usr/bin/ksh* but I am not sure if it is ksh93 or not.

Comment: Try this: `$ printf "%T\n" "now + 10 days"`

Comment: It returns the following error =>   -bash: printf: `T': invalid format character

Comment: Do you have a `gdate` command?

Comment: `gdate` is also missing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you still can do this with perl or python oneliners, e.g., substract one day from current date:

```
$ date
Thu May 14 15:31:49 MEST 2015
$ python -c "from datetime import datetime, timedelta; print (datetime.now() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%c');"
Wed May 13 15:31:58 2015
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the intention is to do it using shell (sh or bash) .

Comment: Even though answer of @nolan6000 is an ideal one but I am unable to use it because I do not have permissions to install new packages on hte server. So it seems only your answer seems to work in my scenario, hence marking it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is **GNU date** for Solaris. (Linux uses GNU tools)

If you are using a recent version of Solaris (no my friend, Solaris 10 can no longer be considered a *recent* version of Solaris) then it is installed by default. Just use `gdate` command instead of `date` command.

This [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27319442) has more answers for you. Just follow the links in that reply for what to do on Solaris 10. You sysadmin may already have done this for you. Before you proceed: Have you checked if `gdate` is available on your system ?

Comment: `gdate` is missing on my Solaris version. But I think the approach you told is an ideal one ( and hence upvote ) but I am not allowed to install any new stuff on those servers.